# Error when uploading a DataFrame to server as a table with an array vector using Python API

Tags: dolphindb

I tried the example given in the [DolphinDB Python API documentation](https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3#2-upload-python-objects-to-dolphindb) to use the `table` method to upload a DataFrame with arrays of different lengths to DolphinDB as a table with array vector.

Version information:

python 3.7

DolphinDB server 1.30.19 on Windows

Python API 1.30.19.2

Here’s the script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dolphindb as ddb
s = ddb.session()
s.connect("localhost", 8848, "admin", "123456")
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'value': [np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],dtype=np.int64),np.array([11,12,13,14],dtype=np.int64),np.array([22,13,11,12,13,14],dtype=np.int64)]
        })
tmp = s.table(data=df, tableAliasName="testArrayVector")

print(s.loadTable("testArrayVector").toDF())
```

I got these errors:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB server 1.30 doesn’t support array vector as a table column.

Download the 2.00 server version and run the script again.